# Error doing Random Forest from data frame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, random-forest, decision-tree

I am performing a random forest on my data frame using pandas, but I can't seem to get it right, my data frame contains two columns with nonbinary values (letters), so I think that's why it's not letting me divide the data into values and attributes. My code is below. For reference, columns 0 and 7 are the nonbinary columns

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    new_df.head()

    X = new_df.iloc[:, 1:16].values
    y = new_df.iloc[:, 16].values

    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)'

    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

    sc = StandardScaler()
    X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

when I input this the error I get is "could not convert string to float: 'TCGA-CH-5740'

```
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

    regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=20, 
    random_state=0)
    [enter image description here][1]regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

the columns drag more to the right but are not captured in the pic

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: X = new_df.iloc[:, 1:16].values
y = new_df.iloc[:, 16].values.                            in this part, how can I write all the columns except the non binary ones (#0 and #7)

Comment: df.select_dtypes or sklearn's OneHotEncoder seem erlevant here

Answer (score 0):

Since a decision tree operates by splitting a feature based on it's value e.g "is this value greater than 5? Is it greater than 10?" then it requires that the features are numbers.
I would assume that sklearn automatically converts all data to floats first, but since you have some columns that contains strings that cannot be converted to a number e.g `TCGA-CH-5740` it fails.

One way to overcome this is by using OneHotEncoding to convert your "string" to numbers, or another implementation that accepts categorical values such as LightGBM or CatBoost